# Current filename not visible in airline

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline

I'm using airline in vim on the terminal (as part of spf-13, fyi). However, all kinds of other random info (including other open buffers) tends to fill up the line and push out or cover what the name of the current file I'm editing is, like so:

```
NORMAL  +5 ~1 -0  master  <.test --ipdb      python  env_awi  utf-8[unix]   33%   44:  2
```

`.test --ipdb` is the the name of one of the open buffers (not the current one) and is partially cut off by the `<.` to the left of which are the other open buffers which are covered up.  Any way to make the current file the only one that shows up, so I know which file I'm currently editing?

Comment: just a silly question - how do you manage to copy the statusline ? I would like to ask another question about airline.

Comment: I just shift-highlighted and copied from tmux.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, it works with vim, but not with gvim, any idea ?

Comment: Just take a screenshot! I wish Carpetsmoker had done so, because my browser messes up his example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With like 5min work  reading `:help airline` I now realize airline is super customizable. I added the following to my .vimrc which replaces the line number percentage 33%   44:  2 (which I never use) with the current filename:

```
let g:airline_section_z = '%t'
```